# Can anyone enlighten me on $e^{-x} = \alpha x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, transcendental-equations

I have worked for quite a while on a statistical problem and has been able to simplify the problem to an equation with a variable I have been seeking, $q$.

The equation is
$$
e^{-q} = \alpha q
$$

where $q$ and $\alpha$ are

- $ \alpha =  e^{-(\theta_d + \theta_{\rho}\frac{r_{n}t}{n} + \theta_i + 1)}$
- $ q = 1 + \theta_d(1-\hat{d}) $

and, $\hat{d} \in (0,1]$ is the actual value I am interested to have on closed form. Everything is real valued, but the specifics doesnt really matter so wont go into detail.

From what i've gathered this is called a trancendental function and typically requires numerical solutions. My question is if there is anything I can do with this equation? Are there any tricks to solve this for $q$ or $\hat{d}$ ? Is there anything I can infer from $\alpha$ for when this equation does and does not have a supported solution?

Comment: Look into https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Nice tip, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{-q}=aq$$

The equation is an algebraic equation (a polynomial equation) of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($q,e^{-q}$). We cannot rearrange the equation for $q$ by elementary functions we can read from the equation therefore.

[Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is one of only a few [Special functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) that can invert polynomial equations with two algebraically independent monomials. Lambert W is not an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

For applying Lambert W, we have to try to rearrange the equation to $f(q)e^{g(q)}=c$, where $c$ is a constant.

$$e^{-q}=aq$$
$$1=aqe^q$$
$$aqe^q=1$$
$$qe^q=\frac{1}{a}$$
$$q=W\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)$$